# how can I return the DBTIMEZONE name

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran

```
select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone
from dual
```

which returned -04:00 and -06:00, respectively.

I also ran

```
select
  TZ_OFFSET('US/Eastern') "EST_offset",
  TZ_OFFSET('America/Denver') "Mtn Time offset"
from dual
```

which returned the same numbers.

My question is, how can I convert "-04:00" into something like "US/Eastern"?  Is there a simple built-in function I am overlooking, or do I need to write my own CASE statement to create this relationship?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814202/oracle-retrieve-by-tzname-is-it-possible did you see this? This may be helpful for you

Answer (score 5):

First of all, why do you like to get `DBTIMEZONE`? I cannot imagine any reason why somebody would need it. DBTIMEZONE is relevant only for TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE columns, it defines the storage format.

I assume you are more interested in time zone of your database server's operating system. This you can select by

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR') FROM dual;
```

Related to your actual question: No, that is not possible. Time zone `-04:00` is different to time zone `US/Eastern`. There are many other time zone regions which have also an UTC offset of 4 hours, see this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tzname
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING CHR(0) FROM TZ_OFFSET(tzname)) = '-04:00';

TZNAME
=========================================
America/Anguilla
America/Aruba
America/Asuncion
America/Boa_Vista
America/Caracas
America/Cuiaba
America/Curacao
America/Detroit
America/Fort_Wayne
America/Guadeloupe
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Indianapolis
America/Iqaluit
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/La_Paz
America/Louisville
America/Manaus
America/Martinique
America/Montreal
America/Montserrat
America/New_York
America/Porto_Velho
America/Puerto_Rico
America/Santiago
America/St_Thomas
America/Thunder_Bay
America/Tortola
America/Virgin
Brazil/West
Canada/Eastern
Chile/Continental
EST5EDT
Etc/GMT+4
US/East-Indiana
US/Eastern
US/Michigan
```

The mayor difference between `-04:00` and `US/Eastern` is: Time zone region like `US/Eastern` apply daylight saving times, `-04:00` does not.

`-04:00` is always 4 hours beyond UTC, no matter if summer or winter season.

[Documentation for TZ_OFFSET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG254) says "*Returns the time zone offset that corresponds to the entered value, based on the date that the statement is executed*"

So, if you would have executed `TZ_OFFSET('US/Eastern')` two weeks ago, the result would have been `-05:00`.

You can change time zone of your database serer operating system to values like `US/Eastern`. However, I don't know whether `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR')` will always return values like `-04:00`, resp. `-05:00` or the region name.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Oracle Community thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3689051):

> Q: How can I find out what is the time_zone of my database?
>
> A: Do you mean the system time zone (`EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)`) or the database time zone (`DBTIMEZONE`)? These are different values used for different purposes.
>
> Oracle Database does not know the region name of the system time zone. Oracle Database determines the system time zone by subtracting UTC time from local time, both retrieved from the operating system. The calculated difference is the system time zone in offset form. When daylight saving time gets into effect in the operating system, the offset changes automatically. **You have to retrieve the time zone region name directly from the operating system using one of the available database interfaces to the outside world** (Java, external C callouts, a local web service started on your host and accessed via UTL_HTTP, etc.)
>
> The database time zone is determined at database creation time and it defaults to `'00:00'`. If it was set to an offset, `DBTIMEZONE` returns the offset. If it was set to a region name, `DBTIMEZONE` returns the region name. I recommend leaving DB time zone at offset `'00:00'` so that `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` may be used to store UTC-normalized time values.